# javascript countdown timer pause resume

Tags: javascript, timer, countdowntimer

At first my countdown timer has no pause and resume function and the timer runs just fine. Now I just added the feature, have no problem pausing but having problem resuming the time. The time just would not display from where it was and countdown from there on. How do I change my codes?

```
$('#pause').click(function(){

    // Get current minutes and seconds //

    var text = $('#countdown').html();

    var min_sec = text.split(":");

    pause_minutes = min_sec[0];

    pause_seconds = min_sec[1];

    // Stop the timer //

    clearTimeout(stop_start);

    // Hide pause button, show the play button //

    $('#pause').hide();

    $('#cont').show();

});

// continue button is clicked //

$('#cont').click(function(){

    $('#cont').hide();

    $('#pause').show();

    // Pass in pause_minutes and pause_seconds //

    resume_time(pause_minutes, pause_seconds);
});

function resume_time(pause_minutes, pause_seconds){ // e.g: 1 , 30

    var start_time = new Date();

    end_time.setMinutes(start_time.getMinutes() + pause_minutes);

    end_time.setSeconds(start_time.getSeconds() + pause_seconds);

    update_timer();
}

function update_timer(){

    var current_time = new Date();

    var remaining_time = new Date();

    remaining_time.setTime(end_time.getTime() - current_time.getTime());

    var minutes = remaining_time.getMinutes();

    var seconds = remaining_time.getSeconds();

    if(seconds < 10){

        seconds = '0'+seconds.toString();
    }

    $("#countdown").text(minutes+":"+seconds);

    // call itself every second if //

    if(minutes == '0' && seconds == '00'){

        $('.big_words').html('Sorry, times up');

        $('.overlay').show();

        setTimeout(function(){
            location.reload();
        }, 2000);

        exit;
    }
    stop_start = setTimeout(update_timer,1000);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote a little timer for you to get into it ;-)

and a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/rnQ2W/2/

```
var CountDown = (function ($) {
    // Length ms 
    var TimeOut = 10000;
    // Interval ms
    var TimeGap = 1000;

    var CurrentTime = ( new Date() ).getTime();
    var EndTime = ( new Date() ).getTime() + TimeOut;

    var GuiTimer = $('#countdown');
    var GuiPause = $('#pause');
    var GuiResume = $('#resume').hide();

    var Running = true;

    var UpdateTimer = function() {
        // Run till timeout
        if( CurrentTime + TimeGap < EndTime ) {
            setTimeout( UpdateTimer, TimeGap );
        }
        // Countdown if running
        if( Running ) {
            CurrentTime += TimeGap;
            if( CurrentTime >= EndTime ) {
                GuiTimer.css('color','red');
            }
        }
        // Update Gui
        var Time = new Date();
        Time.setTime( EndTime - CurrentTime );
        var Minutes = Time.getMinutes();
        var Seconds = Time.getSeconds();

        GuiTimer.html( 
            (Minutes < 10 ? '0' : '') + Minutes 
            + ':' 
            + (Seconds < 10 ? '0' : '') + Seconds );
    };

    var Pause = function() {
        Running = false;
        GuiPause.hide();
        GuiResume.show();
    };

    var Resume = function() {
        Running = true;
        GuiPause.show();
        GuiResume.hide();
    };

    var Start = function( Timeout ) {
        TimeOut = Timeout;
        CurrentTime = ( new Date() ).getTime();
        EndTime = ( new Date() ).getTime() + TimeOut;
        UpdateTimer();
    };

    return {
        Pause: Pause,
        Resume: Resume,
        Start: Start
    };
})(jQuery);

jQuery('#pause').on('click',CountDown.Pause);
jQuery('#resume').on('click',CountDown.Resume);

// ms
CountDown.Start(120000);
```

Comment: @DerDu, is it possible to use this script on server side using socket.io and emit it to the clients? I am trying to put this in a chess application but unable to get started.

Comment: sry, but i don't know anything about socket.io ^^ .. this script is just pure client side js (jQuery-Plugin)