# This code doesn't work in notepad++ when I copy and paste if from jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was looking at this code from this page [javascript countdown timer pause resume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23262434/javascript-countdown-timer-pause-resume) and I looked at the code

```
var CountDown = (function ($) {
// Length ms 
var TimeOut = 10000;
// Interval ms
var TimeGap = 1000;

var CurrentTime = ( new Date() ).getTime();
var EndTime = ( new Date() ).getTime() + TimeOut;

var GuiTimer = $('#countdown');
var GuiPause = $('#pause');
var GuiResume = $('#resume').hide();

var Running = true;

var UpdateTimer = function() {
    // Run till timeout
    if( CurrentTime + TimeGap < EndTime ) {
        setTimeout( UpdateTimer, TimeGap );
    }
    // Countdown if running
    if( Running ) {
        CurrentTime += TimeGap;
        if( CurrentTime >= EndTime ) {
            GuiTimer.css('color','red');
        }
    }
    // Update Gui
    var Time = new Date();
    Time.setTime( EndTime - CurrentTime );
    var Minutes = Time.getMinutes();
    var Seconds = Time.getSeconds();

    GuiTimer.html( 
        (Minutes < 10 ? '0' : '') + Minutes 
        + ':' 
        + (Seconds < 10 ? '0' : '') + Seconds );
};

var Pause = function() {
    Running = false;
    GuiPause.hide();
    GuiResume.show();
};

var Resume = function() {
    Running = true;
    GuiPause.show();
    GuiResume.hide();
};

var Start = function( Timeout ) {
    TimeOut = Timeout;
    CurrentTime = ( new Date() ).getTime();
    EndTime = ( new Date() ).getTime() + TimeOut;
    UpdateTimer();
};

return {
    Pause: Pause,
    Resume: Resume,
    Start: Start
};
})(jQuery);

jQuery('#pause').on('click',CountDown.Pause);
jQuery('#resume').on('click',CountDown.Resume);

CountDown.Start(120000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rnQ2W/2/ I copied and pasted the code into notepad++ but the code didn't work when I run it.

Comment: The console of the browser will tell you the problem

Comment: Are you sure you added jQuery source?

Comment: do you have a plugin installed in notepad++ to run javascript?

Comment: "I copy and pasted the code, but it doesn't work!" - Could say the same if i blindfold copy-paste the code from the first moon mission to my RaspberryPi ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several reasons why your code that you copy/pasted didn't work...

1. make sure you have the following in the `body` of your html:

   ```
   <div id="countdown">00:00</div>
   <a href="#pause" id="pause">Pause</a> <a href="#resume" id="resume">Resume</a>
   ```
2. Since the code makes use of jQuery, make sure you are including the jQuery lib in the `head` of your html

Paste the following in your Notepad++ and save it as an html file (e.g. `countdown.html`) and then open it in your browser...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <title>Countdown</title>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(function() {
        var CountDown = (function ($) {
            // Length ms 
            var TimeOut = 10000;
            // Interval ms
            var TimeGap = 1000;

            var CurrentTime = ( new Date() ).getTime();
            var EndTime = ( new Date() ).getTime() + TimeOut;

            var GuiTimer = $('#countdown');
            var GuiPause = $('#pause');
            var GuiResume = $('#resume').hide();

            var Running = true;

            var UpdateTimer = function() {
                // Run till timeout
                if( CurrentTime + TimeGap < EndTime ) {
                    setTimeout( UpdateTimer, TimeGap );
                }
                // Countdown if running
                if( Running ) {
                    CurrentTime += TimeGap;
                    if( CurrentTime >= EndTime ) {
                        GuiTimer.css('color','red');
                    }
                }
                // Update Gui
                var Time = new Date();
                Time.setTime( EndTime - CurrentTime );
                var Minutes = Time.getMinutes();
                var Seconds = Time.getSeconds();

                GuiTimer.html( 
                    (Minutes < 10 ? '0' : '') + Minutes 
                    + ':' 
                    + (Seconds < 10 ? '0' : '') + Seconds );
            };

            var Pause = function() {
                Running = false;
                GuiPause.hide();
                GuiResume.show();
            };

            var Resume = function() {
                Running = true;
                GuiPause.show();
                GuiResume.hide();
            };

            var Start = function( Timeout ) {
                TimeOut = Timeout;
                CurrentTime = ( new Date() ).getTime();
                EndTime = ( new Date() ).getTime() + TimeOut;
                UpdateTimer();
            };

            return {
                Pause: Pause,
                Resume: Resume,
                Start: Start
            };
        })(jQuery);

        jQuery('#pause').on('click',CountDown.Pause);
        jQuery('#resume').on('click',CountDown.Resume);

        CountDown.Start(120000); 
    });
</script>


</head>

<body>
    <div id="countdown">00:00</div>
    <a href="#pause" id="pause">Pause</a> <a href="#resume" id="resume">Resume</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Andreas; ahh! my mistake... had submitted the edit prior to the addition of the html file related code....

Comment: @Andreas the original fiddle does not include jQuery as an external resource but  the `HTML` posted in my edit does include a CDN version of jQuery...

Comment: @Andreas actually, I indeed stand corrected; sure, the jQuery lib exclusion by OP was an issue that needed to be addressed... however, you are absolutely correct in that there was no page readiness detection surrounding the execution of the countdown... I have amended the changes in my answer, above. Good catch.

Comment: Thank you that makes much more sense

Comment: But what if I want to run more than 1 time how would I do that?

Comment: @PoppyLee meaning multiple countdown timers?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I mean. Like I have different levels and I want them to have different countdown timers.

Comment: @PoppyLee, that wasn't the question... if an answer solves your question, mark it solved and if you have a new question, start a new thread. The way I see it, a question should be to the point and not a "build upon" type.